# strange php output on an if equals

Tags: php, if-statement, equals

I have uploaded a version on a server and I get an error which I did not have on local environment. 
I have this object

```
stdClass Object (
    [type] => education 
    [tutor_title] => Computer skills for the workplace 
    [tutor_title_description] => portland college 
)
```

and when I do this block:

```
if ('education' == $qualification->type)
{
    echo 'yes';die();
}
else 
{
    echo 'no';die();
}
```

I always get no. I don't know why. I have tried to do:

- `if ('education' === $qualification->type)`
- `if ($qualification->type == 'education')`
- `if ($qualification->type === 'education')`

and same output. This is strange why is this happening?

Comment: What's the output for `echo $qualification->type`?

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. It gives more precise information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you do `var_dump($qualification);`? Is there perhaps a space after "education" or so?

Comment: i get this: `object(stdClass)#24 (3) { ["type"]=> string(11) "education " ["tutor_title"]=> string(33) "Computer skills for the workplace" ["tutor_title_description"]=> string(16) "portland college" }`

Comment: What do you mean with 'there is no space'? In your var_dump there is a space ;)

Comment: Now you know there is a space, delete that space at the place where you construct the object. And you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if ('education' == trim($qualification->type))
```

In case there are any space characters around type.